# React native page navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my index file I have a `renderScene` method which renders a component based on the `route.id`

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
  switch(route.id) {
    case 'explore':
      return <PageExplore navigator={navigator} />;
    break;
    case 'post':
      return <PagePost navigator={navigator} />;
    break
  }
}
```

In the `render` method of these pages I have another component which is used to display a couple of links

`<Navbar navigator={this.props.navigator} />`

The links in the `Navbar` component have a `onPress` event. The question is, how do I map these to routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic onPress function would look like this if your renderScene method is as described as above:

```
_navigate(id)
  this.props.navigator.push({
    id: id
  })
)
```

Anything passed to `this.props.navigator.push({})` is available on the `renderScene` method as a property of route.

I've published a pretty extensive writeup on using the navigator [here](https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30).